# Retrieve data from a database and separate the data when we get a delimiter?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a table with two columns first column is the ID and second column is a list Which is of the form :

```
productid:3,productname:EggBiryani,quantity1price:100;
productid:5,productname:Vegetable Biryani,quantity1price:100;
productid:10,productname:Special Vegetable Biryani,quantity1price:130;
```

When i am retrieving this column i need to place a \n instead of ;. as need to send this data via mail it is not clear for identification so if i include \n in place of ; the data after /n will come to next line so that the data will be clear.Thanks in advance

Comment: You clearly have a [normalization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). I assume you are working with a legacy database?

Answer (score 0):

in javascript:

```
var newcol2 = oldcol2.replace(/;/, "\n");
```

or

```
var arycol2 = oldcol2.split(';');
```

in php:

```
$newcol2 = str_replace(";", "\n", $oldcol2);
```

or

```
$arycol2 = explode(';', $oldcol2);
```

references: [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) from the php manual.